# What is the difference, PXSelector vs PXDBScalar

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to figure out when to use PXDBScalar.  Do you guys know the difference between PXSelector and PXDBScalar and when to use which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short PXDBScalar is normally used for unbound DAC fields (not stored in the table).  For example if you wanted to have a Vendor name handy within a DAC fetch you could configure a DAC field with the vendor name without having to actually store it in the table.  Also this works well with GI's.

PXSelector is an attribute for a DAC field that will allow the GUI to perform a look up of 'possible values' as related to the field.

The below explanations are from help.acumatica.com.

```
PXDBScalar:
Defines the SQL sub request that will be used to retrieve the value for the DAC field.

You should place the attribute on the field that is not bound to any particular database column.
The attribute will translate the provided BQL Search command into the SQL sub request and insert it into the select statement that retrieves data records of this DAC. In the BQL command, you can reference any bound field of any DAC.
Note that you should also annotate the field with an attribute that indicates an unbound field of a particular data type. Otherwise, the field may be displayed incorrectly in the user interface.
You should not use fields marked with the PXDBScalar attribute in BQL parameters (Current, Optional, and Required).

PXSelector:
Configures the lookup control for a DAC field that references a data record from a particular table by holding its key field.
```